# How can I earn bits (gold) and gems quickly in the My Little Pony android game?

Tags: android, my-little-pony

Seriously, a building can cost 30K bits but I only make 50 per minute. It will take me 10 hours of mindless grinding just to purchase that one building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask another pony to work so you can make the second thing in a shop - like bread. And don't forget to raise both Bon Bon and Twilight to full star, especially Twilight because when she'll be a princess she has to be a five-star pony.
Build more shop, complete quest and save them. Don't use bits for decoration, except if it's a quest and complete quests that has bits as reward.

Hope that help. :) (Pinkie's big grin and Fluttershy's soft sweet smile)

Answer (score 2):

It seems from the [Pony Website](http://www.gamezebo.com/games/my-little-pony-friendship-magic/walkthrough-cheats-strategy-guide) that there are four major ways to get coins, gems can only be bought or earned through quests.

- Quests can give you coins
- collecting from certain buildings
- Helping out a friend
- Mini-games

It seems that the apple game and the flying game earn you the most coins per minute. The full guide is on the website.

[image: Flying Game]

[image]

Pictures from the Guide listed above.